# WooCommerce Hook after Biiling form completed, and before payment Gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I need to call a function after than the client completed the billing form, but before the payment gateway. This function needs to use the billing form informations...
Is there a Hook for that ?

I tried to do it with:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'create_contact_and_deal', 10, 1 );
function create_contact_and_deal($order_id=0, $status_transition_from="", $status_transition_to="", $instance=NULL) { ...
```

But the function is not called when I complete the billing form..

Comment: You can look into the order status hooks.  Orders are 'Pending' after they are placed, this is before the payment gateway returns successfully.  As order statuses are updated, the hook will fire. You'll need conditional logic to ensure that the hook only fires in the direction you want it. Status from -> Status to.  Good Luck

Comment: I tried to do it :
`add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'create_contact_and_deal', 10, 1 ); 
function create_contact_and_deal($order_id=0, $status_transition_from="", $status_transition_to="", $instance=NULL) {
...`
 But the function is not called when I complete the billing form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing parameters when you setup your add_action.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'create_contact_and_deal', 10, 1 );
function create_contact_and_deal($order_id=0, $status_transition_from="", $status_transition_to="", $instance=NULL) {

}
```

Should be:

```
function action_woocommerce_order_status_changed( $this_get_id, $this_status_transition_from, $this_status_transition_to, $instance ) { 
    // make action magic happen here...
    if($this_status_transition_from == "pending" && $this_status_transition_to == "processing") 
      //Perform stuff when condition is met. 
    {

} 

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'action_woocommerce_order_status_changed', 10, 4 );
```

The most important part is the fourth parameter of the `add_action` function.`,1` in your example only passes the first parameter, the ID.  `,4` will give you the statuses when each changes. That last value indicates how many parameters will be passed to your callback function.